# How to create internal service with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

Is there any way to block directly access to some service(not all) by network with ServiceStack?

I create a service for internal process. this service will be called by other services, but not called by clients directly.

However all service has default endpoint, so internal service is opened by network.

How to create internal service with ServiceStack?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the [Restricting Services Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/auth/restricting-services) for examples of how to use the `[Restrict]` attribute to restrict the accessibility or visibility of your service. E.g:

To limit the **accessibility** and **visibility** to only requests coming from an internal network you can do:

```
[Restrict(InternalOnly = true)]  
public class MyService { ... }
```

If you only want to hide it's visibility (i.e. in externally viewed metadata pages) you can do:

```
[Restrict(VisibleInternalOnly = true)]  
public class MyService { ... }
```